# Iteration formula for fraction

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, derivatives

[image]

**Above is taken from** [Closed form solution for quadratic recurrence iteration function derivation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4193317/closed-form-solution-for-quadratic-recurrence-iteration-function-derivation?rq=1)

Dear readers, In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Examples about closed form solution for quadratic recurrence iteration, **the above picture is the solution**. However, when i tried $g(x)$ that is **non-linear**; for example $g(x) = x/(x+a)$ with $h(x)=x^{2^n}$, this iteration method does not work. **Is the formula that is $f^{\circ n}(x)=g^{-1} h^{\circ n} g(x)$ works only for linear?**

Comment: $g(x)=x/(x+a)$ is not invertible

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please type your questions rather than posting images. Images can't be browsed, and are not accessible to those using screen readers. If you need help formatting math on this site, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial.  To begin with, surround all math expressions (including numbers,) with `$` signs. Use ^ for exponents and _ for subscripts. `$x_1^{2/3}$` shows up as $x_1^{2/3}$.

Comment: Not quite. Your $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ are not of compatible iteration types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\,g(x) := \frac{x}{x+a}\,$ then $\,
g^{\circ n}(x) = \frac{x}{x[n]_a+a^n}\,$
where $\,[n]_a := \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} a^k\,$
is the closed form of the iteration. This result
can be derived in a few ways. Here is one way.

Define $\,2\times 2\,$ matrices $$ M_i :=\begin{pmatrix}
 a_i & b_i \\ c_i & d_i \end{pmatrix} $$
and corresponding rational functions
$$ f_i(x) := \frac{a_i x+b_i}{c_i x+d_i}. $$
Now, if $\, M_3 = M_1 M_2,\,$ then
$\,f_3(x) = f_1(f_2(x)).\,$
This is an example of a monoid homomorphism.
In particular, the $\,2\times 2\,$ matrix that
corresponds to $\,g(x)\,$ is
$$ M := \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ 1 & a \end{pmatrix}. $$ Now, verify
that $$ M^n = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 \\ [n]_a & a^n \end{pmatrix} $$
and this corresponds to the formula for
$\, g^{\circ n}(x)\,$ given above.

Comment: Hi @Somos, thanks for your reply. I assume you got this rational difference equation formula 
 from wiki on the link above. Do you know how to derive this formula?

Comment: The reason why I use f∘n(x)=g−1h∘ng(x)  is because I actually wish to understand the derivation of this rational difference equation from wiki.

Comment: Hi Somos, thanks for your reply. Great answer. Can i ask you more if I have any questions because you seem to be very good at this haha?

Comment: One question: If g(x)= x^2/(x+a) could this method still be applicable?

Comment: @MaximusSu In the case of $\,g(x)=x^2/(x+a)\,$ the two fixed points are $\,x=0\,$ and $\,x=\infty.\,$ For $\,x=0\,$ you can use $\,h(x)=x^2.\,$ For $\,x=\infty\,$ it would be a challenge. You may ask that as a new question.

Comment: that's true. I will post the question.